# Calling PHP function in itself

Tags: php, recursion

In the following script function clean($data) calls it within it, that I understand but how it is cleaning data in the statement **$data[clean($key)] = clean($value);**??? Any help is appreciated.. I am trying to figure it out as I am new to PHP. Regards.

```
if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
function clean($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $data[clean($key)] = clean($value);
        }
    } else {
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }

    return $data;
}           

$_GET = clean($_GET);
$_POST = clean($_POST);
$_REQUEST = clean($_REQUEST);
$_COOKIE = clean($_COOKIE);
```

}

Comment: You should replace your `ini_get` call with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`. And I'm pretty sure that keys are not escaped - so you might want to test that and remove the `clean($key)` unless they are actually escaped.

Comment: I don't understand the question ... What do you want do know?

Answer (score 1):

**Your Question:**

So if I undertsand correctly you want to know what is the function doing in the line

```
 $data[clean($key)] = clean($value);
```

**The Answer:**

See the prime purpose of the function is to remove slashes from string with php's [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) method.

If the input item is an array then it tries to clean the keys of the array as well as the values of the array by calling itself on the key and value.

In php arrays are like hashmaps and you can iterate over the key and value both with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop like following

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {....}
```

So if you want to summarize the algorithm in your code snippet it would be as under

1. Check if the input is array. If it is not then go to step 4
2. For each item of array clean the key and value by calling clean method on it (Recursively)
3. Return the array
4. clean the input string using stripslashes method
   5 return the cleaned input

Comment: Thanks Hasan, I know what the function is doing but see your step 2. How function clean will clean the data when data is an array since stripslashes will be triggered in else part only?????????? So how if part gives the desired result if data is an array that is my question or concern.

Comment: OK I have seen the answer given by @Cranio and he has explained it quite well what actually the script is and its logic. BTW thanks for all of you................

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it's not cleaning the key but creates a new element with a clean key while the uncleaned key remains.

$a['foo\bar'] : val\ue

becomes

$a['foo\bar'] : val\ue

$a['foobar'] : value

Someone correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll understand the code better if it's put this way:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $key = clean($key); // Clean the key, the
            $value = clean($value); // Clean the value
            $data[$key] = $value; // Put it in the array that will be returned
        }
```

Assuming you have an array like this:
$_POST = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => array('bar' => 'baz'));
the following will happen:

```
Call clean($_POST);
call clean 0
call clean 'foo'
$return[0] = 'foo'
call clean 1
call clean 'bar'
call clean 'baz'
$return[1] = array('bar' => 'baz');
```

You should probably read this: http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Recursion-in-PHP/

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the function is to *clean* an associative array **or** a single variable. An associative array is an array where you define keys and values for that keys; so are special arrays used in PHP like `$_GET` `$_POST` and so on.

The meaning of "cleaning" is to check whether magic quotes are active - this causes some characters in these arrays to be escaped with backslashes when you post dynamic data to a PHP page.
`$_GET["Scarlett"] = "O' Hara"` becomes with magic quotes `$_GET["Scarlett"] = "O\' Hara"`

So if magic quotes are active, the function takes care of this, and slashes are stripped so that the strings retain their correct, not escaped value.

The algorithm checks if the data passed to the function is an array, if not it cleans directly the value.

```
$string = "Escapes\'in\'a string";
clean($string);
```

- is it an array? No. Then return stripslashes(my data)

  $array = array("key\'with\'escapes"=>"value\'with\'escapes", "another\'key"=>"another value");
  clean($array)
- is it an array? Yes. So cycle through each key/value pair with `foreach`, take the key and clean it like the first example; then take the value and do the same and put the cleaned versions in the array.

As you see the function has two different behaviours differentiated by that "if" statement.
If you pass an array, you activate the second behaviour that in turns passes couples of *strings*, not arrays, triggering the first behaviour.

**My thought is that this function doesn't work properly, though.** Anyone got the same sensation? I have it not tested yet but it seems it's not "cleaning" the key/values in the sense of replacing them, but *adds* the cleaned versions along the uncleaned ones.

Comment: Your answer is good elaboration and catches what the script is doing but this script is part of opencart scource and might be working quite well otherwise opencart would fail since the function is defined in its core.